# How to start to write from second line with xlwt?

Tags: python, list, xlwt

I want response like this

```
col1  col2   col3  col4  col5
20    50000   10   40000  90000
21    31000   2000 41000  74000
```

The current response is:

```
20    50000   10   40000  90000
21    31000   2000 41000  74000
```

Here I think `col1`,  `col2` .. are being overwritten how can i solve this ? How can I handle row_num here so that the column values will not replace column names ?

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet('datas', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font_style.font.bold = True

columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
rom_num=0
for col_num in range(len(columns)):
    ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
rows = [20, Decimal('50000.00'), Decimal('10.00'), Decimal('40000.00'), Decimal('90000.00'), 21, Decimal('31000.00'), Decimal('2000.00'), Decimal('41000.00'), Decimal('74000.00')]

for i,e in enumerate(rows):
    row_num += 1
    ws.write(int(i/5),int(i)%5, e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify the `start` parameter in the [`enumerate(iterable, start=0)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```py
for i,e in enumerate(rows, start=1):
    row_num += 1
    ws.write(int(i/5),int(i)%5, e)
```

Similarly the [`range(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-range) also supports starting on a custom index if necessary:

```py
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']
rom_num=0
for col_num in range(1, len(columns)):
    ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style
```

Comment: I have one question is there any way to change the column size based on the text here?

Comment: @D_P as in the width? I don't think it's possible with XLWT. Though it's a deprecated package nevertheless. Perhaps try [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io) and its [`openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html#module-openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions).